# How to debug PowerShell process whithout error message or exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell

I am trying to run the following PowerShell script from within my .NET application:

```
try {
    Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ArgumentList "--headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=c:\myDir\file.pdf https://www.bing.com"
$x = "Complete" 
$x | Out-File C:\myDir\error.txt
}
Catch {
    $_ | Out-File C:\myDir\error.txt
}
```

Simply, the above will create a pdf based upon bing.com website

In my dev environment it runs fine as a PowerShell script. It also runs fine on the production server (again, as a PowerShell script).

The issue occurs when I invoke this PowerShell script from my web app on the production server. My C# code is

```
var command = "c:\myDir\ps.ps1";
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "powershell.exe";
psi.Arguments = command;
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = psi;
process.Start();
```

This works fine on my dev machine. It fails on the production server. The `error.txt` file is written to disc which suggests it's not a permissions issue. However, the content of the `error.txt` file always shows "complete". It never errors.

So, it appears that the catch in the PowerShell script is never being hit. As such, no error message. There is no exception thrown in the C# code. Regardless, it isn't working.

How can I debug this?

Or, if easier, I'm happy to run the code directly instead of invoking the PowerShell script file but the following also does 'nothing'.

```
 var command = $"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" -ArgumentList \"--no-sandbox --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf={imagePath} {fullUrl}";
```

Comment: For one, you can simplify it by removing PowerShell from the equation - just launch Chrome directly with Process.Start. Then, you can start redirecting the process stdout and stderr to see if any errors occur.

Comment: I don't fully understand @RB. I can already prove that the script is running because it always updates (or creates) the `error.txt` file. I can also run the actual powershell script and it executes as expected

Comment: First rule of debugging - simplify your problem... At the moment you have a layer of indirection in your code. Removing that, and logging stdout and stderr directly might expose additional information that can help you solve your issue. Of course, it might not - but it will take about 30 minutes to check, and you've already waited a week so far :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem. It is caused by the fact that web application on your production server is running under the user that is not currently logged in. It is running under identity of assigned application pool. Chrome has [known issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167556) of not working correctly if it's launched under the user different from currently logged user. If you check that link, you will see that issue was registered in December 2012 and still is not resolved. You could easily reproduce the problem if launch Chrome under the different user ("Run as different user" in shortcut context menu when called with pressed Shift). In this case Chrome will not open any page and will just show gray screen.

The [workaround](https://superuser.com/questions/1026344/running-chrome-as-an-alternate-user-while-logged-in-with-different-credentials) is to launch Chrome with `--no-sandbox` switch. Google actually does not recomment this. However if you run Chrome in automated way to access trusted source, I believe it's ok.

So to fix the problem modify `start-process` in the script in the following way:

```
start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ArgumentList "--no-sandbox --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=c:\myDir\file.pdf https://www.bing.com"
```

**UPDATE**

I have underestimated the problem at first. Now after additional research and many tried approaches I can propose solution that works.

I didn't manage to fix your current approach of direct launch of powershell and chrome from Web Application. Chrome just fails to start and following errors appear in Event log:

```
Faulting application name: chrome.exe, version: 64.0.3282.186, time stamp: 0x5a8e38d5
Faulting module name: chrome_elf.dll, version: 64.0.3282.186, time stamp: 0x5a8e1e3d
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset: 0x00000000000309b9
Faulting process id: 0x11524
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3bab1a89e3b4f
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\64.0.3282.186\chrome_elf.dll
Report Id: e70a5a36-26a4-11e8-ac26-b8ca3a94ba80
```

This error occurrs even if you configure application pool to use identity of some existing (ordinary) user that could launch the chrome.
May be it's possible to configure IIS or application pool to prevent these errors but I have not found the way.

My proposal is to switch from starting powershell process from controller action to scheduling a task with Windows task scheduler.

Here are the steps that should be taken to accomplish this task:

1. On your production server create a user under which the Chrome will be started. I'll refer to created user as 'testuser'.
2. Login under `testuser`, start chrome, open some site. Without this step, the flow was not successfully, probably because of missing chrome user account.
3. Grant "Log on as a batch job" right for `testuser`. This step is required for successfull execution of scheduled tasks under `testuser`. The procedure is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14259467/5740031)
4. Add `--no-sandbox` argument to the script as I described in my initial answer.
5. Replace the code of `Process.Start()` with scheduling of the task job.

[The easiest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks) to schedule a task from .Net is via [TaskScheduler NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/). Install it to your application and add following code:

```
string powerShellScript = @"c:\myDir\ps.ps1";
string userName = @"YOURCOMP\testuser";
string userPassword = "TestPwd123";

using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
{
    TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
    td.Triggers.Add(new RegistrationTrigger
    {
        StartBoundary = DateTime.Now,
        EndBoundary = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
    });
    td.Settings.DeleteExpiredTaskAfter = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("powershell.exe", powerShellScript));
    ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition($@"Print Pdf - {Guid.NewGuid()}", td, createType: TaskCreation.Create, userId: userName, password: userPassword, logonType: TaskLogonType.Password);
}
```

In above code snippet change the name and password for `testuser`.

With this approach your script is successfully executed and pdf is printed successfully.

**Update by OP**

If the above continues to fail, then again, check the Event Viewer logs. In this case, I had an issues with a message similar to `The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID {20FD4E26-8E0F-4F73-A0E0-F27B8C57BE6F} and APPID Unavailable` but it was resolved by granting [permissions for the CLSID](http://blog.paulgu.com/windows/permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-launch-permission-for-the-com-server-application-with-clsid/). Further, try to run the task in task scheduler by itself, such as create a new task to simply launch notepad or similar to make sure that this is working with the account you want to test. In my case, I had to use the administrator account.

Comment: Thanks. I am in the office in about 10 hours time where I can test this! Obviously I'll come back but +1 already

Comment: Just tried. Sadly it has no impact. The same issue persists

Comment: What is the identity of the pool in which the application runs on production? Is it local system account?

Comment: The application pool identiy is `ApplicationPoolIdentity`

Comment: This seems like a very intelligent approach. Does the code create a one off task but leave it (meaning, it appears as if there is no clean up operation)

Comment: `td.Settings.DeleteExpiredTaskAfter = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);` takes care of task deletion.

Comment: I need to play with this when I'm back in, which again is about 10 hours. Thank you. I also get the same error message in the event viewer.

Comment: For step 2, do I need to log in or simply run chrome as?

Comment: I'd suggest to log in as user. This is a way I have tested it and I'm sure this flow works. Haven't tested it for "run as".

Answer (score 1):

You have to redirect the stdin and stdout so that it sends it from powershell.exe back to the parent process (your web app). I modified your code sample to do this:

```
var command = "c:\myDir\ps.ps1";
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "powershell.exe";
psi.Arguments = command;

psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = psi;
process.Start();

process.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput);
Console.WriteLine(process.StandardError);
```

Comment: Did you mean `process.StandardError`

Comment: Whilst I found this useful, it doesn't help. If you see @CodeFuller post, he mentions the exception being thrown and logged in event viewer. As such, this post won't help as Chrome is going kaboom for a reason

Answer (score 1):

I think additional to what *CodeFuller* said having no sandbox with `--no-sandbox` option,  you should also disable all extensions, sync and bookmarks.

The best is having a **Guest session** alias *"browse without sign-in"* with`--bwsi` option.

What is funny is that during testing I have found out that it is better, got better pdf printout, to disable extensions explicitly with `--disable-extensions` before doing `--bwsi`.

I have tested it and for me it works.  I'm looking forward for your feedback.

**Edit1 and Edit3** - removing try...catch and adding user & password and adding **psuser** specifics

You are probably on domain so I have adjusting the script to run as different user on domain (the user must have correct rights!)

First create your credentials file with:

Login to user e.g. **psuser**

Create the password file:

```
# Encrypt user password and save it to file
Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File 'C:\<your_path>\your_secret_password.txt'
```

Then run the below improved script with encrypted credentials:

```
$username = 'psuser' # This needs to be adjusted to correct user you are using 
$domain = <your_domain> # adjust to your needs

$encrypted_passwd = get-content 'C:\<your_path>\your_secret_password.txt' | ConvertTo-securestring



# Setting process invocation parameters.
   $process_start_info = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
   $process_start_info.CreateNoWindow = $true
   $process_start_info.UseShellExecute = $false
   $process_start_info.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
   $process_start_info.RedirectStandardError = $true
   $process_start_info.UserName = $username
   $process_start_info.Domain = $domain
   $process_start_info.Password = $encrypted_passwd
   $process_start_info.Verb = 'runas'
   $process_start_info.FileName = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
   $process_start_info.Arguments = '--no-sandbox --disable-extensions --bwsi --headless --disable-gpu  --print-to-pdf=C:\prg\PowerShell\test\chrome_file.pdf https://www.bing.com'

   # Creating process object.
   $process = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Process
   $process.StartInfo = $process_start_info

   # Start the process
   [Void]$process.Start()

   $process.WaitForExit()

   # synchronous output - captures everything
   $output = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
   $output += $process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()

   Write-Output $output
```

During the script debugging I have encountered these errors:

a) When you want to validate against a AD server but it is not available:

```
Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request"
At C:\prg\PowerShell\test\chrome_print.ps1:56 char:12
+            [Void]$process.Start()
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception

Exception calling "WaitForExit" with "0" argument(s): "No process is associated with this object."
At C:\prg\PowerShell\test\chrome_print.ps1:58 char:12
+            $process.WaitForExit()
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\prg\PowerShell\test\chrome_print.ps1:61 char:12
+            $output = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\prg\PowerShell\test\chrome_print.ps1:62 char:12
+            $output += $process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

b) Missing domain information in the script:

```
Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The stub received bad data"                            
At C:\prg\PowerShell\test\chrome_print.ps1:39 char:12                                                   
+            [Void]$process.Start()                                                                     
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                     
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException                           
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception                                                            

Exception calling "WaitForExit" with "0" argument(s): "No process is associated with this object."      
At C:\prg\PowerShell\test\chrome_print.ps1:41 char:12                                                   
+            $process.WaitForExit()                                                                     
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                     
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException                           
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException                                                 

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.                                                   
At C:\prg\PowerShell\test\chrome_print.ps1:44 char:12                                                   
+            $output = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()                                              
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                              
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException                                
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull                                                        

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.                                                   
At C:\prg\PowerShell\test\chrome_print.ps1:45 char:12                                                   
+            $output += $process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()                                              
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                              
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException                                
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Prints the pdf

[image: Printed PDF]

and the *stderr* messages:

```
[0313/112937.660:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1009)] Lost UI shared context.
[0313/112937.662:ERROR:instance.cc(49)] Unable to locate service manifest for metrics
[0313/112937.662:ERROR:service_manager.cc(890)] Failed to resolve service name: metrics
[0313/112938.152:ERROR:instance.cc(49)] Unable to locate service manifest for metrics
[0313/112938.153:ERROR:service_manager.cc(890)] Failed to resolve service name: metrics
[0313/112942.876:INFO:headless_shell.cc(566)] Written to file C:\prg\PowerShell\test\chrom e_file.pdf.
```

**Edit2** Adding windows account impersonation with *ASP.NET*

Impersonate a windows account with *ASP.NET*:
ASP.NET user is not passed into the new threads (by default).  When you want to invoke PowerShell script it is invoked in other thread with different credentials (you can overcome that with above script when you have a dedicated domain authenticated user for running the above script).  By default the script is executed under build-in account `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`.

These steps are to overcome it on `ASP.NET` level:

1) Enable Windows Authentication in IIS
  a) Install it first (this is windows 2008 R2 screenshot):

[image: Install the windows Authentication]

b) enable it on your IIS:

[image: Disabled IIS windows authentication]

Change it to enabled:

[image: Enabled windows authentication on IIS]

2) Change your site's web.config to correctly handle impersonation

Edit the web.config file in your site’s directory.  In order to execute the server side code of the current user's security context (AD).

Find the xml tag: `<system.web>` and add two new elements to enable the `windows authentication`

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="True" />
```

3) To correctly write code to invoke in-process PowerShell script

You need to adjust your *ASP.NET* code in a way that you will have powershell Runspace and you will invoke the script inside the Runspace in a pipeline

A quick example:

```
// You need to create a Runspace. Each other pipeline you create will run in the same Runspace
// Do it only once, all others will be pipelined
RunspaceConfiguration powershellConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
var powershellRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(powershellConfiguration);
powershellRunspace.Open();

// create a pipeline the cmdlet invocation
using ( Pipeline psPipeline = powershellRunspace.CreatePipeline() ){
    // Define the command to be executed in this pipeline
    Command script = new Command("PowerShell_script");

    // Add any parameter(s) to the command
    script.Parameters.Add("Param1", "Param1Value");

    // Add it to the pipeline
    psPipeline.Commands.Add(script);

    try {
        // Invoke() the script
        var results = psPipeline.Invoke();
        // work with the results
    } catch (CmdletInvocationException exception) {
    // Any exceptions here - for the invoked process
    }
}
```

4) Modify `aspnet.config` to allow impersonation to cross threads

This step allows you to run as your current, impersonated, user.

You have to modify your servers’s `aspnet.config` file.
Add two xml elements to the `configuration` and `runtime`:

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
...
<legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="true" />
<alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="false" />
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Sadly, the same issue continues :s

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions could you show me your stdout & stderr?

Comment: I can, but please give me about 8 hours until I can test it

Comment: One more question.  Under which user you are running it on production?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that @tukan. How do I find out? I simply publish the website and it seems to just work. If you mean within IIS, it's set to run under ApplicationPoolIdentity

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions the scripts you are executing are executing via inbuilt account `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`.  I'll show you how to impersonate from `ASP.NET`.  Anyways, for security reasons you should have a dedicated user (running the powershell scripts) and run it from its account.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions you can now try it to impersonate the script directly via the powershell script (easier) - just add your user on the server as username and create your password.   The other options is to impersonate your script via *ASP.NET*